# How can i make function work in event driven module?

Tags: php

well this is event driven module i have trouble with creating new handler like $qm->addEventListener('adding', function($x){$x = 5;}); and then 
$qm->addEventListener('adding', function($x){echo $x;}); how can i make work something like this? it return nothing.

```
<?php
class Event {
    private $eventName;
    function __construct($eventName){
        $this->eventName = $eventName;
    }
    public function name() {
        return $this->eventName;
    }
}
class QueueManager {
    private $registeredHandlers = array();
    public function addEventListener($eventName, $handler) {
        if (!is_array($this->registeredHandlers[$eventName]))    $this->registeredHandlers[$eventName] = array();
        $this->registeredHandlers[$eventName][] = $handler;
    }
    public function dispatch($event) {
        $eventName = $event->name();
        if (!$this->registeredHandlers[$eventName]) return;
        foreach ($this->registeredHandlers[$eventName] as $handler) $handler();
    }
}

$qm = new QueueManager();
$qm->addEventListener('click', function(){echo 'ok1';}); //something like this working
$qm->addEventListener('click', function(){echo 'ok2';});
$qm->addEventListener('adding', function($x){$x = 5;});  //something like this not working
$qm->addEventListener('adding', function($x){$x++;});
$qm->addEventListener('adding', function($x){echo $x;});
$clickEvent = new Event('click');
$qm->dispatch($clickEvent);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult, as you need not only to pass variables to the adding event handler, but pass by reference as well

You need to modify your event callbacks to handle the call by reference as well; then taking advantage of PHP 5.6 variadics:

```
class Event {
    private $eventName;
    function __construct($eventName){
        $this->eventName = $eventName;
    }
    public function name() {
        return $this->eventName;
    }
}
class QueueManager {
    private $registeredHandlers = array();
    public function addEventListener($eventName, $handler) {
        if (!isset($this->registeredHandlers[$eventName]) || !is_array($this->registeredHandlers[$eventName]))    $this->registeredHandlers[$eventName] = array();
        $this->registeredHandlers[$eventName][] = $handler;
    }
    public function dispatch($event, &...$args) {
        $eventName = $event->name();
        if (!$this->registeredHandlers[$eventName]) return;
        foreach ($this->registeredHandlers[$eventName] as $handler) call_user_func_array($handler, $args);
    }
}

$qm = new QueueManager();
$qm->addEventListener('click', function(){echo 'ok1';}); //something like this working
$qm->addEventListener('click', function(){echo 'ok2';});
$qm->addEventListener('adding', function(&$x){$x = 5;});  //something like this not working
$qm->addEventListener('adding', function(&$x){$x++;});
$qm->addEventListener('adding', function($x){echo $x;});

$clickEvent = new Event('click');
$qm->dispatch($clickEvent);

$addingEvent = new Event('adding');
$value;
$qm->dispatch($addingEvent, $value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer out here:
[php event system implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316576/php-event-system-implementation)

It shows you how to correctly write a dispatch.